# How to use CSS Overflow: hidden to avoid the parent container grow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fix width column and a fluid column. Inside the fluid column I want to put a string with nowrap and do not show the text outside the container.
This is how I like to view the text:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
|       |                                                |
| 200px | fluid width div fluid width div fluid width ...|
|       |                                                |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

but when the text is too long the container div grows and shows all the text no matter how long the text is.

This is my sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/Autociudad/8137gf7g/4/

HTML code:

```
<div class="table-layout">
    <div class="table-cell fixed-width-200">
        <p>fixed width div</p>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        <p class="text">fluid width div fluid width div fluid width div fluid width div fluid width div fluid width div fluid width div fluid width div </p>    
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.text {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.table-layout {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.table-layout .table-cell {
    display:table-cell;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
}

.fixed-width-200 {
    width:200px;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue is due to adding `display:table` to the wrapper element and `display:table-cell` to the "cells."

Alternatively you can use a `float:left` for the 200px width cell and remove the custom `display` settings: http://jsfiddle.net/8137gf7g/7/

```
.text {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.table-layout {
    width:100%;
}
.table-layout .table-cell {
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
}

.fixed-width-200 {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an explicit width on `.text` so that it knows which width it should start hiding content after (i.e. how to do the calculation):

```
.text {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:100px;
}
```

The `white-space:nowrap` is preventing it from its normal fluid behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/8137gf7g/5/

Comment: Thanks but I like to show more text than fixed 100px. I like to show text according to the parent width.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is perfect only you need to set is

```
.text
{
display: inline-block;
width: 300px;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```